# MongoDB Distinct Count issue

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have collection with following data (Collection contains more than 10 million records)

```
> db.LogBuff.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16c"), "SUBJECT" : "DD", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16d"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16e"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f16f"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f170"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f171"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f172"), "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f173"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f174"), "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f175"), "SUBJECT" : "DD", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f176"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f177"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f178"), "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "D" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f179"), "SUBJECT" : "DD", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f17a"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f17b"), "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f17c"), "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578899d5d2b76f77d083f17d"), "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "C" }
```

I want to get the following kind of output

```
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "C" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "DD", "SYS" : "A" }, "COUNT" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "B" }, "COUNT" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "C" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "B" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "A" }, "COUNT" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "C" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "AA", "SYS" : "A" }, "COUNT" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "A" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "CC", "SYS" : "D" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "SUBJECT" : "BB", "SYS" : "B" }, "COUNT" : 1 }
```

This is my code

```
db.LogBuff.mapReduce(     
    function(){          
        emit( { SUBJECT : this.SUBJECT, SYS : this.SYS } , this.SYS);     
    },       
    function(key,values){          
        return $count:1  <-stuck here  
    } 
)
```

Due to some limitations I can't use the Aggregation method. I used the following aggregation code:

```
db.LogBuff.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:{SUBJECT:"$SUBJECT",SYS:"$SYS"},COUNT:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{_id:1}},])
```

While this works for a limited number of records, for large amounts it returns this error (note - I am not the root user, therefore I can't change the configuration):

> assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", "code" : 16819 } :
>   aggregate failed _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

Comment: Tried using Aggregation framework? or you must use MapReduce only?

Comment: I used Aggregation , but it work for limited no of recored , large amount it return following memomry error (i am not the root user theirfore i can't change the configurations)

Comment: assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
        "code" : 16819
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14

Comment: Why are you sorting after grouping? You've posted a desired output that is unsorted, yet you're passing it in as an aggregation stage. It doesn't have enough memory to pull all those documents and then sort them. You shouldn't have an issue if you drop the sort. More info can be found in the [docs about sorting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-and-memory-restrictions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use allowDiskUse option:

```
db.LogBuff.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:{SUBJECT:"$SUBJECT",SYS:"$SYS"},COUNT:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{_id:1}}], {allowDiskUse: true})
```